# google people api: assign/create contact group

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-people-api

I cannot figure out how to create a new contact group and assign it to the contact using google people api in php. An error

> "person.memberships is a read only field."

occurs at $person->setMemberships():

```
    $contactGroup=new Google_Service_PeopleService_ContactGroup();
    //$contactGroup->setGroupType('USER_CONTACT_GROUP');
    $contactGroup->setName('Some group');
    $contactGroup->create();
    $cgm=new Google_Service_PeopleService_ContactGroupMembership();
    $cgm->setContactGroupId('groupID');
    $membership=new Google_Service_PeopleService_Membership();

    $membership->setContactGroupMembership($cgm);
      $person=new Google_Service_PeopleService_Person();

      $groupMemberships=array(($membership));
      $person->setMemberships(array($groupMemberships));//error happens here
```

Anyone could help with a proper example of creating  contact group and assigning it to the contact?

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory.  You cant set the person.membership field its read only.

Answer (score 4):

The following code assumes you have instantiated a `Google_Client` object, and have already created a person and know their ID.

Resource ID example,

```
$person_id = 'people/1234567890abcde';
```

Create a contact group,

```
$peopleService = new Google_Service_PeopleService($client);

$newContactGroup = new Google_Service_PeopleService_ContactGroup;
$newContactGroup->setName('New contact group');

$createContactGroupRequest = new Google_Service_PeopleService_CreateContactGroupRequest;
$createContactGroupRequest->setContactGroup($newContactGroup);

$contactGroup = $peopleService->contactGroups->create($createContactGroupRequest);

$contact_group_id = $contactGroup->getResourceName();
```

Add a person to contact group,

```
$peopleService = new Google_Service_PeopleService($googleClient);

$modifyContactGroupMembersRequest = new Google_Service_PeopleService_ModifyContactGroupMembersRequest;
$modifyContactGroupMembersRequest->setResourceNamesToAdd($person_id);

$peopleService->contactGroups_members->modify($contact_group_id, $modifyContactGroupMembersRequest);
```

Comment: many thanks, I figured out how to assign a group. But as far as I understand there is no possibility to assign an external ID to the contact and search for a contact using that ID. Kind of strange, because Android contacts have this possibility. I intended to sync contacts with our CRM it looks like it is not that easy and identify google contacts by the contact ID used in CRM :(.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set members of the contact group in the creation call. You need to create the contact group in one call, then in a second call add it using [members.modify](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups.members/modify) api call.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I cannot assign the contact group, because I don't get resourceName from the $result = $peopleService->people->createContact($person); Any ideas why? Docs state I should get Person object with resourceName